# HttpError 403 'forbidden' - trying to update video description

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, http-status-code-403

I am trying to write a python script that will update a video's description in YouTube via YT-api-v3.

I have OAuth2.0 configured in my Google API Console, and can successfully authenticate on running the script by getting credentials and creating an api client (I am prompted to enter the provided code, and the auth screens all work in the browser) but then I get snagged with the below error....

`<HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&alt=json returned "Forbidden". Details: "[{'message': 'Forbidden', 'domain': 'youtube.video', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]">`

This happens in response to calling

```
youtube.videos().
update(part="snippet,id", body=dict(snippet=videos_list_snippet, id=id_video)).
execute()
```

...as outlined in the YouTube api `.update()` example

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a video you own, posted in the account you authenticated with?

Comment: Yes, a video uploaded to my own channel.

Comment: That's not Python code.  Are you using a Python module, or are you sending HTTP requests directly?

Comment: Hmm, not sure exactly. I'm using python to call the YouTube api, as outlined here: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/update_video.py

Comment: My mistake.  I should have recognized that was one long line.  You have triple-checked your credentials in `client_secret.json`?  You have followed the instructions to enable API access for your videos?